# How to fetch data for forecast with a given interval as parameter for a particular city

Tags: c#, .net, openweathermap

I am creating a prototype app for a subject at uni where I need to fetch data from: https://openweathermap.org/api

Additionally, I am using the HTTP client (.NET 6 based proejct) to send requests to the API.

Can anyone help me, how should I construct the full url with all the necessary query parameters for the following scenario:

Fetch data for a particular city (1st parameter) and second parameter which is optional should be:

- Get the current weather (if the second parameter is null)
- 1 Hour Forecast
- 2 Day Forecast
- 7 Day Forecast

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.